# PHP in_array doesn't work or work strange

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Sorry for my bad English , but i have problem which i cant solve.
I have arrays which contains arrays with key "tags" (i will call it tag-array).In some tag-arrays are same values so i want create one array which will contain values from tag-arrays without repetition.

list of values i have in tag-arrays:

```
=================
php
bootstrap
html
css
=================
php
=================
bootstrap
=================
laravel
=================
php
```

Example of array which contain tag-array :

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [project_name] => Something 5
                [info_1] => Some test information 1
                [tags] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => php 
                        [1] =>  html 
                        [2] =>  bootstrap 
                        [3] =>  css
                    )
                [img_1] => 1.jpg
            )
         [1] => Array(...)
         [2] => Array(...)
         [3] => Array(...)
         [4] => Array(...)
}
```

What i did to make new sorted array :

```
public function sortTags($data){
        $works_number = $this->getCountWorks(); //count arrays
        $new_arr =  array();
        for($i=0; $i < $works_number; $i++){
            foreach ($data[$i]['tags'] as $key => $val) {
                if(!in_array($val, $new_arr)){
                    array_push($new_arr, $val);
                }
            }
        }
        echo "Debug : <br /> <pre>";
        print_r($new_arr);
        echo "<pre>";
    }
```

What expected :

```
Array
(
    [0] => php 
    [1] =>  html 
    [2] =>  bootstrap 
    [3] =>  css
    [6] => laravel
)
```

Real resault (take a look that i have one more array where is also "php" but function sorted it and didn't write) :

```
Array
(
    [0] => php 
    [1] =>  html 
    [2] =>  bootstrap 
    [3] =>  css
    [4] => php
    [5] => bootstrap
    [6] => laravel
)
```

So why my fucntion dont do what i want (and how fix it) and why function SORTED LAST ELEMENT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code didn't work because you have whitespace around some of the tags. You need to [`trim`()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) them before pushing them into the array. If you want them sorted, you need to call [`sort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort) on the array.

```
public function sortTags($data){
    $works_number = $this->getCountWorks(); //count arrays
    $new_arr =  array();
    for($i=0; $i < $works_number; $i++){
        foreach ($data[$i]['tags'] as $key => $val) {
            $val = trim($val);
            if(!in_array($val, $new_arr)){
                array_push($new_arr, $val);
            }
        }
    }
    sort($new_arr);
    echo "Debug : <br /> <pre>";
    print_r($new_arr);
    echo "<pre>";
}
```

Comment: @ZELIBOBA This is why you should use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()`. It shows more details, including the length of the strings.